# Calling vim in subprocess after running cat

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, vim, stdin

I am trying to create a bash function `vim_run` which operates as follows:

- user pipes command output into `vim_run`
- user can edit output
- user exits vim and the contents of that buffer are now executed via `source file`

This flow is useful for editing a list of files one wants to remove. I have it currently implemented as

```
function vrun() {
    local tmpfile=$(mktemp)
    cat > "$tmpfile"
    vim "$tmpfile" --not-a-term
    source "$tmpfile"
    rm "$tmpfile"
}
```

however, I cannot figure out how to make vim behave properly with respect to stdin and the terminal. Whenever I pipe output into this function, e.g.

```
echo 'echo foo' | vim_run
```

after editing the contents and exiting vim, it breaks my terminal: it doesn't show characters when I type. Only when I invisibly type `stty sane` does it go back to normal. I vaguely understand that vim needs access to stdin in order to work properly; however, after the `cat > $tmpfile` finishes, shouldn't the remaining stdin be available to vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixes it for me:

```
function vrun() {
    local tmpfile=$(mktemp)
    cat > "$tmpfile"
    vim "$tmpfile" < /dev/tty
    source "$tmpfile"
    rm "$tmpfile"
}
```

We must just redirect the controlling TTY of the session to be Vim's stdin.

Comment: Thank you! This definitely works. Do you know why this needed? How does the input redirection of the preceding cat command affect it?

Comment: It is needed because the entire function runs with a redirected standard input when we do `echo grep foo | vrun`.   The standard input of every command inside the `vrun` function is that `echo` process. The `cat` comand reads all of that input and puts it into a temporary file.  But the other commands also have that `echo` as their standard input: `vim`, `source` and `rm`.    So all we are doing is, for the `vim` command, replacing the redirected standard input with the controlling TTY.   In a terminal session that's what would have been the standard input if `vrun` had not been redirected.

Comment: There exist interactive, visual programs (with a terminal screen interface) which can be used in the middle of pipelines. They work by opening `/dev/tty`.   For instance the `less` program. You do `command | less`, yet `less` reads intearctive input from the terminal. That input isn't coming from the command; `less` has to open the TTY explicitly.

Comment: That makes sense -- thanks!